# Erro de restrição em relacionamento OneToMany Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-jpa

Estou obtendo erro no relacionamento OneToMany, quando tento persistir uma entidade.

Erro:

`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "book_url_id" violates not-null constraint Detalhe: Failing row contains (2, name, pattern, temp, type, null).`

BookUrl.java:

```
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "book_urls")
public class BookUrlEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1216319313385073856L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String url;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "bookUrl")
    private Set<BookUrlParameterEntity> parameters;
}
```

BookUrlParameterEntity.java

```
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "book_url_parameters")
public class BookUrlParameterEntity implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1388929732076588240L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "variable_name")
    private String variableName;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "variable_type")
    private String variableType;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "variable_pattern")
    private String variablePattern;

    @Column(name = "variable_temp_value")
    private String variableTempValue;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = true)
    private BookUrlEntity bookUrl;
}
```

Estou tentando a persistência dessa maneira:

```
BookUrlEntity book = BookUrlEntity.builder().url("www.com.br").build();
BookUrlParameterEntity p1 = BookUrlParameterEntity.builder()
        .variableName("asd")
        .variablePattern("asd")
        .variableType("asda")
        .build();
BookUrlParameterEntity p2 = BookUrlParameterEntity.builder()
        .variableName("asd")
        .variablePattern("asd")
        .variableType("asdw")
        .build();
BookUrlParameterEntity p3 = BookUrlParameterEntity.builder()
        .variableName("asd")
        .variablePattern("asd")
        .variableType("asdq")
        .build();
Set<BookUrlParameterEntity> params = new HashSet<BookUrlParameterEntity>();
params.add(p1);
params.add(p2);
params.add(p3);
book.setParameters(params);

bookUrlRepository.save(book);
```

Já procurei em outros lugares sobre relacionamento, mas é um pouco confuso ainda pra mim, que estou começando com Spring, Hibernate.

Comment: O erro é bem claro, ao persistir `BookUrlParameterEntity` o campo `bookUrl` está nulo e viola a restrição que uma chave estrangeira não pode ser nula. Você precisa debuggar e ver o por quê esse objeto está indo nulo

Comment: Exatamente nessa parte que não estou obtendo êxito. Não entendo o motivo da não atribuição do ID na tabela de parâmetros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No código que você adicionou podemos ver o problema, os objetos **p1, p2** e **p3** estão com campo `bookUrl null`. Adicione o objeto `book`nas variáveis p1, p2 e p3. seria algo como:

```
BookUrlParameterEntity p1 = BookUrlParameterEntity.builder()
        .variableName("asd")
        .variablePattern("asd")
        .variableType("asda")
        .bookUrl(book)
        .build();
```

O mesmo com **p2** e **p3**.

Como você está utilizando o Lombok, e possui um relacionamento bidirecional é preciso excluir o campo **bookUrl** na classe **BookUrlParameterEntity** com esta anotação:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude="bookUrl")
```

Para mais informações: [Documentação @EqualsAndHashCode](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode)

Comment: Quando faço isso, dá um erro `java.lang.StackOverflowError at com.teste.manager.models.entities.BookUrlEntity.hashCode(BookUrlEntity.java:30) at com.teste.manager.models.entities.BookUrlParameterEntity.hashCode(BookUrlParameterEntity.java:24) at java.util.AbstractSet.hashCode(AbstractSet.java:126)`. Parece que ele entra em um tipo de loop

Comment: Funciona caso eu salve primeiro o BookUrl. Mas essa seria a abordagem correta?

Comment: Não sou familiarizado com Lombok mas você possui uma dependência bidirecional entre `BookUrlEntity` e `BookUrlParameterEntity`. O erro acontece no Equals e HashCode `com.teste.manager.models.entities.BookUrlParameterEntity.hashCode` pelo que pesquisei você pode adicionar esta anotação `@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude="bookUrl")` na classe `BookUrlParameterEntity`. [doc @EqualsAndHashCode](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode) explica porquê o erro stackoverflow

Comment: @DiegoHenrique Como você anotou o campo `parameters` com `CascadeType.ALL`,  abordagem correta é salvar o bookurl mesmo.

Comment: Adicionei a annotation EqualsAndHashCode e foi corrigido o problema. Poderia atualizar a resposta para que eu possa aceita-la? Muito obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: @DiegoHenrique Por nada, atualizado !